# Persist File Session during Laravel 5 Capistrano Deployment

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy a Laravel 5 application which uses the file session driver. What do I have to do, to persist the current session during within a new release (deployment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Capistrano::Laravel](https://github.com/capistrano/laravel/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/laravel.rake#L46) defaults to the following `linked_dirs`

```
  "storage/app",
  "storage/framework/cache",
  "storage/framework/sessions",
  "storage/framework/views",
  "storage/logs"
```

I use them in my `deploy.rb` like this

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push(
    'public/uploads',
    'storage/app',
    'storage/framework/cache',
    'storage/framework/sessions',
    'storage/framework/views',
    'storage/logs'
)
```

And the file session are persisted in between different Capistrano deployments.